# Using AJAX to change div content - how do I display navigation as hash / anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a page that refreshes content within a div async alongside providing a user with an anchor to enable direct access to the content within the div. (e.g. www.website.co.uk/#page1)

I've managed to make it so that the content can be updated for 1 page, however, if I add multiple pages it stops working

Additionally - if I was to navigate to the URL website.co.uk/#page1 it wont display #page1.

Can anyone help?

This is my current code:

**HTML :**

```
<h5> <a href="#page1">Test</a></h5>
<h5> <a href="#page2">Test2</a></h5>
```

**JS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var routes = {
        '#page1' : '{{site.url}}/page1'
        '#page2' : '{{site.url}}/page2'
    };
    var routeHandler = function( event ) {
        var hash = window.location.hash, 
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", routes[hash], true);
        xhttp.send();    
    };
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', routeHandler);
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (routes.hasOwnProperty(hash)) routehandler();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've added Shillys Answer underneath, however, if I was to navigate directly to a page (e.g. www.website.co.uk/#page1) it doesnt display the content needed

Comment: Have you placed a comma after each route but the last? The routes object you show here, is invalid, which the debugger should tell you. Are the urls to the other pages correct and is the ajax call returning the correct html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made some small js errors.
So here is you fixed code

**html**:

```
<h5> <a href="#page1">Test</a></h5>
<h5> <a href="#page2">Test2</a></h5>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
  //change these routs
  var routes = {
    '#page1': '/page1.html',
    '#page2': '/page2.html'
  };

  var routeHandler = function() {

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", routes[window.location.hash], true);
    xhttp.send();

  };

  window.addEventListener('hashchange', routeHandler);
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(window.location.hash)) routeHandler();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You usually use a router-like object for this. Instead of the hyperlink you're using, set the href to the actual page hash `<a href="#page1">Button Title</a>`. Then create an event listener for the hashchange on the window object where you will fetch the content.

And finally add a list of webpages you want to be able to navigate to, so you can translate '#page1' to the actual url.

The result is that you can use simple hrefs in your hyperlinks and the current page will be shown in the url bar at the top.

ps: add a check into the hashchange listener for routes that aren't listed, so you can still link to offsite pages as well.

pps: If you want to be able to directly navigate to a page, you'll need to add a manual check of the hash at document load.

```
// html mockup
<a href="#page1">Button Title</a>
// js mockup
var routes = {
    '#page1' : '{{site.url}}/webpage.html'
};

window.addEventListener('hashchange', function( event ) {
    var hash = window.location.hash, // gives you '#page1'
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", routes[hash], true);
    xhttp.send();    
});
```

Updated with a load listener:

```
// html mockup
<a href="#page1">Button Title</a>
// js mockup
var routes = {
    '#page1' : '{{site.url}}/webpage.html'
};
var routeHandler = function( event ) {
    var hash = window.location.hash, // gives you '#page1'
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", routes[hash], true);
    xhttp.send();    
};
window.addEventListener('hashchange', routeHandler);
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(hash)) routehandler();
});
```

Comment: You were faster than me. I just wanted to recommend `window.onhashchange` syntax.

Comment: I prefer addEventListener for all my events, so you can add multiple listeners for the same event. If you use `window.onhashchange = fn` in one part of your app, and then use it again later, you'll overwrite the first listener using the object.onsomething syntax. Same is true for clicks, etc.

Comment: Right, but I just prefer to minimize the number of magic strings in my code. What's better, depends on the case.

Comment: Thank you Shilly - this code now changes the div content when a button is pressed (and displays the desired URL) ... however, if I navigate to the provided URL it doesn't display the updated content in the div ... please can you clarify on how to achieve this (sorry for being a pain)

Comment: After thinking about it, I only partially understand what you mean Mate, and start wondering what downside there is to using this syntax. Now that I think of it, I use alot of magic strings to avoid objects having a dependency on eachother.

Comment: I've added the updated code and it still doesn't work - if a user navigates to www.websiteurl.co.uk/#page1 it wont display page1 ... it displays the original page

Comment: Also, when I add 2 routes, it doesnt seem to work (even the first one doesnt work)

Answer (score 2):

since you have tagged the question with jquery, iassume you have jQuery available, in this case you could do something like:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', refreshContent);

function refreshContent() {
    $.get(getBaseUrl() + location.hash, function(data) {
         $('#div1').html(data);
    });
}
```

But please be aware that there are a lot more sophisticated solutions out there

Answer (score 2):

I given directly on `onclick` its working. It may help you.

```
<h5> <a href="#page1" onclick="test('#page1')">Test</a></h5>
<h5> <a href="#page2" onclick="test('#page2')">Test2</a></h5>
<div id="div1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var routes = {
        '#page1' : 'page1.html',
        '#page2' : 'page2.html'
    };
    function test(page) {

        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", routes[page], true);
        xhttp.send();    
    }

</script>
```

I used `.html` for pages for check. You use your own.